# How to change permalink to include custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, functions, permalinks

Is there a way to add custom post type to permalinks with a plugin or otherwise?

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

mysite.com/projects/food/burgerking
mysite.com/projects/wine/cherryvineyard
mysite.com/projects/liquor/thebodaga

Comment: Can you try this? https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Comment: I did but it seems to add the category to the permalink not the custom post type.